# Understanding JavaScript's call function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap my head around the call and apply functions in JavaScript and I came up with a device for helping me understand what they are doing but I wanted to check that it is correct before I commit it to memory.

The device is

`x.method.call(y, z)` is in effect calling `y.method(z)` where `method` only exists for `x`.

Is this true for all cases? Am I totally offtrack? Is there a better way to think about this?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825652/when-should-i-use-call-vs-invoking-the-function-directly)

Comment: Just think of it as setting the value of `this` in the function you're calling. Doesn't work for functions created using `.bind()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is mostly correct, and is a reasonable way to think about it. What actually happens is doing `x.method` without parentheses "unbinds" the function, and changes the value of `this` to `window` (or `undefined` in strict mode). When you then call `call` on the function argument, you change the value of `this` to whatever the first thing you passed to `call` is.

Comment: Saying `x.method` without parentheses "unbinds" the function is probably more confusing. A method is never bound to an object in any meaningful way unless it was actually created using `.bind()`. The value of `this` is entirely based on how the method is invoked, so *assigning* it to a variable, like: `var foo = x.method; foo();` would set `this` to the default because `method` simply has no knowledge of `x` or any other object at the time of invocation.

Comment: Getting `x.method` does do nothing about `this`. Only invoking it is relevant - `foo()` makes `this` being `null` (in strict mode).